# JavaScript RegEx to replace HTML encoding

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, html-encode

I have the following JS code, which I want to replace all my `&#8362;` (₪) with a `$` sign.

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&#8362;/g,'$'));
```

However it's not doing anything. I've also tried to escape the special characters (as I don't know exactly which need to and which don't), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers recreate the HTML as a representation of the DOM when you access `innerHTML` (or jQuery's `html()`).  This means characters that may have been encoded in the original HTML will be encoded in the output for `innerHTML` only if necessary to ensure the resulting HTML can be parsed.  Since *₪* is not a syntactic part of HTML's structure, it won't be encoded.

tl;dr, replace the literal character:

```
.replace(/₪/g,'$')
```

Alternatively, if you're not sure about the encoding of your file, use the Unicode escape sequence:

```
.replace(/\u20AA/g,'$')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems with different IDEs? Maybe not all support this character? For example my Zend Studio gave me an error while saving the script with this character, but it gave me the option to save as UTF-8 and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @EduardLuca: yes, the encoding of the file makes a difference here.  If that's a problem, use the Unicode escape sequence (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 2):

The regex syntax to match on a unicode hex character code is:

```
\uhhhh
```

Where the h's represent a four-digit hex code So:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\u8362;/g,'$'));

// OR if that number was a decimal number, in hex you'd have:
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\u20AA;/g,'$'));
```